# How to tell mouse from touch in onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

It sounds like a trivial question, but I just wasted an hour trying to make a 3rd party long press library work correctly with mouse and touch, while also allowing clicks. It's much harder than I thought, always some small detail is off.

After struggling, I finally *almost* made it work, but there's a last thing I need - I need to make `onClick` handler to run for a mouse, but not for touch. Can that even be done? I'm using React.

```
<button onClick={event => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.pointerType === "mouse") {
        // It's a mouse, but pointerType is not a thing in Safari
    }
}}>
```

Now, I know I can trick it to detect it, setting `useRef()` on mouse down etc., but that's not the point. Is there any specific `onClick` event property that makes it clear that it's a mouse event? I thought at least `event.buttons` would be different, but nah - it's `0` for both mouse and touch.

I also just learned about `onPointerXXX` events, but there's no `onPointerClick`, sadly.

I know that `preventDefault()` for `onTouchStart` does the job, but I can't do it, as the container is scrollable.

Very frustrating.

**EDIT**

For now I added `event.preventDefault()` in `onTouchEnd` and it seems to be working fine by not firing `onClick` at all on touch. It also doesn't block the scrolling. Is there any other default functionality lost that way?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

- Checking the value of `e.type`.
- Checking if `e.touches` is `undefined` (click) or not (touch).
- Using `e.pointerId`. In my case, I always get 1 for real mouse clicks and more than 1 for click events triggered by touch, but you would need to verify if that behavior is consistent. Also, I suspect you are going to have the same issue with Safari...

```js
function handleClickAndTouch(e) {
  const { type, pointerType, pointerId, touches } = e
    
  if (type === 'touchstart' && touches) {
    console.log('This is a touchstart.')
  } else if (type === 'click' && pointerId === 1) {
    console.log('This is an actual click.')
  } else {
    console.log('This is a click triggered by a touch.')
  }
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', handleClickAndTouch)
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', handleClickAndTouch)
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 67px !important;
}
```

```html
Click or tap anywhere
```

Comment: `event.type` is `"click"` and `event.touches` is just not there.

Comment: Yep sorry, I didn't understand the question. `pointerType` is the right option, but if your problem there is with Safari, you might need a workaround for it like setting a flag in the touch event to then ignore the click one. I've updated the answer with an alternative using `pointerId`, but not sure how reliable that is, and you might have the same issue on Safari.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, Safari doesn't have any of these. I actually solved it temporarily by setting `preventDefault()` on `touchend` event. Seems like it doesn't cause unwanted side effects, unless I'm missing something.